# What is the dimension of the nullity of a matrix A if the matrix A is the zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I was under the assumption that given a nxn matrix A ,and we can just take a general example of a 2x2 0 matrix, is the dimension of the nullity of this matrix not 0?

Comment: The nullity is $n$. Remember rank + nullity = $n$, and the rank of the 0 matrix is 0.

Comment: Nullity is the dimension of kernel (a.k.a. null space). For a zero matrix, the whole domain is its null space. Therefore its nullity is...